# Disqus on an amp page inside an amp-iframe

Tags: disqus, amp-html

I try to implement Disqus on an amp document. My idea is to use an [amp-iframe](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/extended/amp-iframe.html)
which loads a small document which only contains Disqus. I used this amp frame

```
<amp-iframe width="300" height="300"
            layout="responsive"
            sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-scripts"
            resizable
            frameborder="0"
            seamless
            src="/disquss/name-of-blog-post">
    <div overflow tabindex=0 role=button aria-label="Read more">more!</div>
</amp-iframe>
```

However, chrome throws a content security policy violation:

> Refused to load the script
>   'https://a.disquscdn.com/next/embed/lounge.load.f3e1717b71e7256da258d3a504e56865.js'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src https://*.twitter.com:*
>   https://api.adsnative.com/v1/ad.json *.adsafeprotected.com
>   https://cas.criteo.com/delivery/0.1/napi.jsonp *.services.disqus.com:*
>   http://referrer.disqus.com/juggler/ disqus.com http://*.twitter.com:*
>   a.disquscdn.com https://referrer.disqus.com/juggler/
>   https://*.services.disqus.com:* *.moatads.com 'unsafe-eval'
>   https://mobile.adnxs.com/mob https://ssl.google-analytics.com".

So basically, chrome does not load `https://a.disquscdn.com/next/embed/lounge.load.f3e1717b71e7256da258d3a504e56865.js` even though `a.disquscdn.com` is allowed. This restriction comes from an iframe disqus uses. This isn't a problem when I use a native sandboxed `<iframe>` instead of an `<amp-iframe>`.

I'd liked to create an example but because of the iframe construct i can't simply create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 6):

It appears to be an instance of this bug:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=541221

The same thing **does** happen with a standard iframe if using the sandbox attribute.

Adding `allow-same-origin` to your sandbox definition seems to fix it. I notice it's the same in Firefox now too despite the comment in that bug (though firefox doesn't list the error as explicitly) that it works there. So maybe this is how it's supposed to work? Can't say I know enough about the sandbox attribute to tell you that.

However, as an aside, I'm not sure this is such a great idea anyway. Will you be having a non-AMP version of this page? Personally I don't see the case for an AMP only page as I think this limits you since 1) not everything is possible in AMP and 2) some clients won't load this (e.g. if no javascript, or doesn't understand AMP), so I prefer to have a real HTML page too. However if you do have separate HTML and AMP pages then they will track comments separately (unless you load your non-AMP page into this iframe and somehow hide everything but the comments - but that seems a complete waste!).

So the way I implement this at present is to add a "click here to view comments" link to my AMP pages which take them to the full page - with comments. Not a great solution but at least keeps comments together.

Comment: Discuss expects a Parameter with the page url so different comment sections wouldn't be a problem. Also yes, I try a complete amp page just to test around. I'll try adding that sandbox attribute later but last time I tried it didn't do anything. I also added the sandbox attribute to the normal Iframe and that did work (but it's possible that I did something wrong there.)

Comment: `allow-same-origin` works but the amp-iframe has one limitation: "They must not be in the same origin as the container unless they do not allow allow-same-origin in the sandbox attribute.". I don't really get why this limitation is there but if i use a different domain than everything is fine.

Comment: Yes I don't get that either. Guess they want you to not use this as a work around to pretend it's an AMP document when it's not. Also confusing wording "do not use same origin unless allow-same-origin not set"?!? Interesting suggestion about passing correct URL to Disqus. Must look into that more as currently I use the defaults which gets it from page URL. Maybe will be possible to get this working on AMP document...

Comment: I found a hack. The browser seems to be case insensitive about the sandbox attribute. amp isn't https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/fd5c8a4cd3b28cc4e6902fc5ebaa74fd11c86f79/extensions/amp-iframe/0.1/amp-iframe.js#L49. So one Solution is: `allow-Same-origin` and never tell someone about this.... I'll report it.

Comment: "and never tell someone about this" 

Comment: I have successfully embedded Disqus comments on AMP pages and written up the how-to here: https://labs.tomasino.org/disqus-in-amp